# Обработка нажатий клавишь с клавиатуры в консольном приложении C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет, у меня есть потоковая обработка List, как мне сделать, что бы после нажатия любой клавиши с клавиатуры обработка заканчивалась ?

```
        //private Dictionary<string, ushort> pairs = new Dictionary<string, ushort>();
        private int countCharacter;
        //private List<string> text;
        private ConcurrentBag<string> text;
        private bool isPressKey = false;

        public string GetStatistics(
            List<string> text, 
            int countTop = 10,
            int countCharacter=3)
        {
            pairs.Clear();
            //this.text = text;
            this.text = new ConcurrentBag<string>(text);
            this.countCharacter = countCharacter;

            Start();

            return gerResultOnString(countTop);
        }
private void Start()
        {
            text.AsParallel()
                .Where(str => str.Length >= countCharacter &&
                                    Regex.IsMatch(str, "^[A-ZА-Я]+$")
                                    && !isPressKey)
                .ForAll(str =>
                {
                    //CheckPressKeyOnKeyBord();
                    checkNode(str);
                });
        }
```

Хочу прерывать работу метода Start() если была нажата любая клавиша с клавиатуры.

Comment: Покажите код и добавьте больше подробностей в вопрос. Так же обратите внимание на мой комментарий под прошлым вашим ответом.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/12.5.php

Comment: просто в нужном месте бросайте исключение `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`